# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos de una lista y agregarlos a otra vacía?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, bucles

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio donde quiero que python ejecute un for que elimine temporalmente un elemento de una lista y luego lo agregue a otra lista vacía. Este es el código que estoy usando.

```
pizza = ['cebolla','ajo','jamón','queso']

 listavacia = []

for ingrediente in pizza:
    ingredientefuera = pizza.pop()
    listavacia.append(ingredientefuera)
print(pizza)
print(listavacia)
```

Pero python me muestra el siguiente resultado:

```
['cebolla', 'ajo']
['queso', 'jamón']
```

Quiero que python llene la lista vacía con los ingredientes de la lista pizza, y que esta última quede vacía. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Estas iterando en la lista pero la lista cambia de tamaño, mejor haz `for ingrediente in len(pizza):`

Comment: en realidad es `for ingrediente in range(len(pizza)):` >_< me olvidé del `range()`

Answer (score 0):

Si ves la lista como un estructura horizontal, el ciclo for recorre contando cada ingrediente desde izquierda a derecha, pero el método pop quita desde el final (de derecha a izquierda) es por eso que a la segunda iteración, correspondiente "ajo" (2° elemento de izquierda a derecha) ya llevas 2 pop's, por lo que el tamaño de tu lista pizza es de 2, y ya a la siguiente iteración el ciclo for no encuentra mas elementos a la derecha en la lista pizza y termina.

La solución a tu problema es asegurándote que se realicen tantas iteraciones como el tamaño INICIAL de tu lista pizza.

```
n = len(pizza)
for i in range(n):
    listavacia.append(pizza.pop())
```